# meteor angular repeat-in over a collection, group objects that have a common key value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I have a collection that I have bound to a scope variable that looks like this:

```
$scope.userzones = [{userid: '1',zone: 'a'},{userid: '2',zone: 'b'},{userid: '3',zone: 'c'},{userid: '4',zone: 'a'},{userid: '5',zone: 'a'},{userid: '6',zone: 'c'}]
```

I was hoping to do a nested ng-repeat to produce a view that kinda looks like this:

```
zone b userids:
2
--------------
zone a userids:
1
4
5
--------------
zone c userids:
3
6
```

I have tried mashing up an array of the collection like this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37028/grouping-elements-in-array-by-multiple-properties

but that produces this error: `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

I have also tried `ng-repeat="userzone in userzones | unique:'zone'"`
but that doesn't display anything.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> [This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and each $digest cycle triggers a state change and subsequent $digest cycle. Angular detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop from causing the browser to become unresponsive.](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig)

What you need is `$scope._userzones = _.groupBy($scope.userzones, 'zone');`

[see the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Cv4NobGb6kegfrAXOBO?p=preview)